# How can I remap the "`" key to "Esc"

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am using a Mac after five years of Linux. I had remapped "Caps Lock" to "Ctrl" and swapped the "`" with Escape.

I was able to figure out how to convert Caps Lock to a Control, but can't figure out how to do the second. Please suggest a good tool so I don't have to undo many years of muscle memory.

(I use OSX Lion)

Comment: With Apple recently removing the Esc key from their keyboards, this is again quite topical. I found additional useful hints in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control which doesn't require a third-party application. For what it's worth, the key on the upper left has the glyph § on it on many Nordic keyboard layouts, rather than ` \` `.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154188/key-remapping-without-karabiner which informs us that KeyRemap4MacBook was renamed Karabiner and then was reborn as Karabiner Elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html)

A preference pane with currently about 1500 remapping options. Includes `` Backquote(`) to Escape `` and `` Escape to Backquote(`) ``.

---

### [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele)

You could create a custom `.keylayout` like this:

[image]

Esc on the layout above worked with all of the things I tested:

- OS X UI actions like canceling a dialog and exiting full screen
- On some websites with keyboard navigation like Google Search
- As a meta key in Terminal.app

Modifying special keys from a `.keylayout` usually results in some unexpected issues though.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of doing this is by using a third party app; [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/). Set it up to look like this :
[image]

Create an applescript with `tell application "System Events" to key code 53` and save it. Then add a new shortcut to BTT which runs the script.

Comment: Hey! This seems like overkill for this, but thanks for letting me know of such a neat tool. I can see a lot of other things I can do with this.

Answer (score 2):

The inconveniently named [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) should do that, without the need for an external applescript.