# Karabiner quit working in Sierra. How do I map my menu/application key to be Command?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have a microsoft keyboard. When I upgraded to Sierra Karabiner quit working.  It was previously mapping my menu/application key to act as pressing the left Command key instead of doing nothing.  How can I repair this behavior.

Comment: See https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/tree/master/usage

Uninstalled existing Karabiner
Installed Karabiner-Elements according to instructions in the link.
Created ~/.karabiner.d/configuration/karabiner.json
With the following JSON inside

```
{
    "profiles": [
        {
            "name": "Default profile",
            "selected": true,
            "simple_modifications": {
                "application" : "right_command"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who are not at ease with json files, you can use [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) [as suggested here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238001/31154)

It allows easily adding of keyboard shortcuts but also additional trackpad gestures, with an easy to use GUI.