# Remap caps lock in macOS Ventura

Tags: keyboard, ventura

There used to be an easy way to remap caps lock to escape in older versions, and in fact that setting remained for the keyboards I had used prior to upgrading to Ventura. Now I need to enable this setting on a new keyboard. Where has it moved to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's under System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts... -> Modifier Keys

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation but needed to remap it to shift. Let me paraphrase [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1804009/) for "Switch the keys caps lock and shift" (SuperUser).

> Unfortunately, <kbd>left Shift</kbd> isn't listed as per the
> conventional way, the other keys are. See it at System
> Preferences->Keyboard, then select the "Modifier Keys" button.

[image: conventional way in settings show other keys of remapping, not shift]

> [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements) is excellent and I'm using it for a few months
> after it fixed my issue. Follow the basic instructions listed for
> installing it on their repo page. As of Aug 2023, it supports macOS 11
> Big Sur and above.
>
> Remapping is as simple as heading over to "Simple Modifications"->"For
> all devices"->"Add item". Both <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>left
> Shift</kbd> as listed under "Modifier keys" in the dropdown menu.

Comment: linking [Key remapping without Karabiner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/154188/)